How to explode string type column in pyspark dataframe and make individual columns in table
I am getting following value as string from dataframe loaded from table in pyspark. It is List of nested dicts. I want to explode and make them as separate columns in table using pyspark.
dataframe col =  [{ser={cos=hon, mgse=yyyyyyyy, bd=1994-06-11}, ap={}, ep={}}, {ser={cos=null, mgse=null, bd=null}, ap={ncd=035, ccd=A, scd2=C, cos=hon, pgse=nnnnnnn, pcd=06, nar=vvvvvvvv}, ep={eptd=bbbb, ept=bbbb}}]

I want to convert this columns as individual cols from each occurance of ser. For example, see what is my expected results.

And I want to further explode ap column and ep column and it needs to be looks like below:

Can someone provide or help me how we can implement it on the string format which is coming from redshift table.
Thanks in Advance.
Bab

You can use the from_json function from pyspark to extract the inner keys. you can refer to this link for further examples.
I'd suggest you explicitly define the desired target schema first, then try to extract the info using from_json. Especially because I can see potential naming conflict in your column names, for example, your ap column has a key cos while another separate column with the same name is present. So you can try the following approach:
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

ap_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('ncd', StringType(), True),
        StructField('ccd', StringType(), True),
        StructField('cos', StringType(), True),
        StructField('pgse', StringType(), True)
        # The rest of your desired keys from ap
    ]
)
ep_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('eptd', StringType(), True),
        StructField('ept', StringType(), True)
        # The rest of your desired keys from ep
    ]
)

df.withColumn("ap", from_json("ap", ap_schema))\
    .withColumn("ep", from_json("ep", ep_schema))\
    .select(col('id'), col('cos'), col('mgse'), col('bd'), col('ap.*'), col('ep.*'))\
    .show()

Use any type for the StructFields in the defined schemas as you desire.

Thank you for your quick response. I tried based on your suggestion but I am getting null when you apply from_json. May be it is not able to parse correctly. I will try and see how can I make it as json format and try to parse it. I will keep you posted on the updates.

Judging by the looks of ap field it seemed like JSON to me. If you tell me the exact data type for that field I will update the answer

Thank you for your response and "ap" is a string field which has list of dicts. For example., I have string type "[{'key1' = 'value1','key2' = 'value2'},{'key1' = 'value3','key2' = 'value4'}]" . This value I want to parse it and get 2 rows for key1 and key2.

please see my example in edited section
